# Making a restart button for an Android app game

Tags: android, eclipse, button

I am working on an android app and when I run the main activity the app runs as I want it to but stops after you die in the game. I want to make a restart button appear after you die in the game. So far I've made a new layout with a button and the background of the main activity. I made a new class in my source folder and have set up an onclicklistener but I'm not sure what code will make the the button start the main activity start again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can add the following code to your onclick method:

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

by adding the following code, you are restarting the same activity... without going back to the previous one.

**UPDATE**

here how you can change and restart the game, you need to add flags to start the activity over.

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainMenu.class); //change it to your main class
    //the following 2 tags are for clearing the backStack and start fresh
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    finish();
    startActivity(i);
```

try it out, hope it works for you

Comment: Just to clarify I didn't make the button in the main activity which is the activity I want to restart. I created a new class that displays a different layout. I'm an amateur obviously so if you need any specifics I can copy the code onto here

Comment: so you want to use a button in different class to restart the game (Create a new instance of the game) and take you back to the main?

Comment: Won't let me post the code cus I'm on my phone but any help is appreciated

Comment: Nevermind I just added the code you mentioned earlier to the end of the main activity and it restarts automatically. Thanks for the advice

Comment: check the updated part... I guess this is what you are looking for. and thanks for accepting my answer

Answer (score 2):

You could just call `Activity.recreate();` if you're api level is 11 or above.