# How to use android mediaplayer on motionevent

Tags: android, motionevent

I am trying to set a sound for a touch for my game but there's an error on the line final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.move); any suggestions? Thx

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x_aux = (int) (event.getX() / (this.getWidth() / x));
    int y_aux = (int) (event.getY() / (this.getHeight() / y));
    drawimage(x_aux, y_aux);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.move);
    setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Is your touch listener an anonymous (inline) instance? If so then `this` will refer to the listener which isn't a valid `Context`. To fix it you could use `MyActivity.this` instead (obvioulsy replace MyActivity with the name of your actual `Activity`.

Comment: Actually what if I just change it into
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.move);
    mp.start();

Im new to android and I am trying to modify someone else's code here to add some features.

Comment: Do you mind taking a look at the complete class?

Comment: If you edit the question to include the full code of the Activity I'll take a look.

Comment: It seems to be too long to be posted here. Here's a dropbox link of a notepad of the code https://www.dropbox.com/s/t0ciqiik15fc3fl/gameclass.txt thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `create(...)` method of `MediaPlayer` requires a `Context` as the first parameter. The problem is likely to be your Game class is a `View` (which doesn't extend `Context`) so using `this` for the first parameter won't work.

You could try holding a reference to the `Context` which is passed into the constructor. Under the private field `private Paint caneta;` add one for the `Context`. Example...

```
public class Game extends View {

    private Cell[][] singlesquare = null;
    int x = 3;
    int y = 3;
    private int l;
    private int a;
    private boolean whatdrawn = false;
    private int playerwin = 3;
    private Paint caneta;
    private Context context; // ADD THIS LINE
```

Then in the constructor save a reference to the `Context` passed in. Example...

```
public Game(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context; // ADD THIS LINE
```

Then when you create the `Mediaplayer` use...

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.move);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked!!! Another feature that I want to add to the game I created a menu and I want to have a restart option. Do I create a method in the main activity or do I need a clear board method on the Game class

Comment: Nevermind I was able to do it thx to this tutorial http://stackoverflow.com/a/22213380/3551857

Comment: It is a Tictactoe 2 player game but I want it to not be able to undo the move can anyone suggest how to implement it. Now if I place a circle on a tile it can be undo with a cross when I press the same tile again.